# Why aren't binaries placed in CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR?

Tags: c++, cmake

It is my understanding that `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` should point to the directory where binaries for the current CMakeLists.txt file will be placed. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Consider this file structure:

```
CMakeTest
+- CMakeLists.txt
+- main.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
add_executable(CMakeTest main.cpp)
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

On the (Windows) command line, I run the following commands:

```
md build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
cmake --build .
```

The first `cmake` command prints (among other things) the line

> CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR = X:/dev/projects/CMakeTest/build

So I'd expect the resulting binary file CMakeTest.exe to end up there. Really, however, it is placed in X:/dev/projects/CMakeTest/build/Debug.

*Why isn't the binary file placed into `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, but in a sub-directory? And is there any CMake variable that tells me what that subdirectory is?*

**Edit:**

I'm not trying to *change* the directory where binaries are placed. I'm trying to *determine* it. The reason is this:

During build, a number of additional resource files are created in the same directory as the executable file. (This part works.) I'd like to use the `install(FILES, ...)` command to then add these files to the resulting package. So I need to pass the actual path where the binaries are placed to `install(FILES, ...)`.

Comment: I guess, this is a shortcoming of MSVC generator.

Comment: I believe this is a good thing.. I mean with debug and release executable being incompatible and likely named the same its best to keep them in separate folders. Remember in MSVC you have 4 configurations by default.

Comment: @arrowd: It doesn't seem to be a generator issue. Using the `Xcode` generator on OS X has the same result.

Comment: And using `Unix Makefiles`?

Comment: @drescherjm: I'm not saying sub-directories are a bad thing. I'm merely asking how to find out where the binaries actually go.

Comment: @arrowd: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to understand CMake behavior, not asking for an alternative.

Comment: I mean that complex generators like XCode and MSVC have their own thoughts on where to put compiled binaries. And CMake doesn't seem to be able to influence that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html) denotes "binary directory currently being **processed**" by CMake. Usually, this directory and its subdirectories contains build *artifacts*, like executables, libraries or other generated files.

If you want to control location of **executable** being built, you need to set variable [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

Note, that *multiconfiguration* build tools, like Visual Studio, for each specific configuration will create subdirectory (named as configuration itself) under *CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY*. Otherwise, executables created for different configurations would overwrite themselves.

For **precise control** of per-configuration directory used for built executables, use variable [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html#variable:CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>). (Instead of *<CONFIG>* name of specific configuration should be inserted, so *CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG* variable will affect *Debug* builds).

---

For just determine directory with executable, use `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) (instead of `tgt` a name of the target created the executable should be used).

Note, that generator expressions can be used only in specific places. E.g., list of files for `install(FILES)` command can use generator expression, but `message()` command cannot.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, @Tsyvarev. I'm afraid I wasn't quite clear in what I'm trying to achieve. I added an "Edit:" paragraph to my question. It would be great if you could have a look at it!

Comment: Looks like you are searching for `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` generator expression, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the executables are often stored at a level below the CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR, based on the build type.  You can navigate to this directory directly by using ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} (which is typically has value of Debug or Release) by building a full path like:
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}